# Accidentally deleted relationship laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

so I have a relationship between two models

```
class Projects extends Model implements Auditable
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    use \OwenIt\Auditing\Auditable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'active'
    ];

    public function boards(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Board::class);
    }
}
```

And

```
class Board extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function projects(){
        return $this->hasMany(Projects::class);
    }

}
```

I wanted to empty the Board from its Projects without deleting the relationship. 
I thought this code would do the trick:

```
$board->projects()->delete()
```

But I ended up deleting the relationship.

My question now is how do I restore the relationship and what would be the best way to empty the relationship without actually deleting it?

EDIT: to further explain
Let's say I have 4 projects belonging to a Board. How would I get rid of all of them at once without knowing the project ID's?

Comment: Not sure you can restore it. What do you mean by `empty the board from its projects`? Do you mean clearing the fields: `name` and `active`?

Comment: Please explain what you mean with `empty the Board from its Projects without deleting the relationship`.

Comment: What I mean is that if 4 projects belong to a Board, I want to be able to empty all projects linked to that board without knowing the ID's of the projects. @commonsense

Comment: @Mozammil If 4 projects belong to a Board, I want to be able to get rid of them all at once without having to know their ID's.

Comment: @Ari They are not deleted from your DB because you defined `use SoftDeletes;`. If you want to delete them completely you can either remove this from your model or use `$board->projects()->forceDelete()`

Comment: It's easy to be general after the battle but you should use git and have DB backup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be able to restore the relationships, because you are using soft deletes in the `Projects` model. You can do this by running:

```
$board->projects()->withTrashed()->restore();
```

Take attention to use the `withTrashed()` method on the query. Then the query will also return the soft deleted projects.

You can "empty" the relationship by making `board_id` nullable in the `projects` table and set the `board_id` to `null`.

You can bulk update the projects by running:

```
$board->projects()->update(['board_id' => null]);
```

EDIT: You can also achieve the bulk update by running `$board->projects()->detach();`, as mentioned by @common-sense.

Comment: Thanks, your first code has worked.
I want to be able to get rid of all related projects without having to know their ID's, though.

Comment: @Ari You can bulk update the projects by running: `$board->projects()->update(['board_id' => null]);`

Comment: There is a dedicated method for this: `$board->projects()->detach()`.

Comment: Thanks, I've added it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't restore deleted data from database, if you have not any backups or you don't use Laravel's [Soft Delete](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#deleting-models) feature.

> If you use already this, you can restore data from db or `->withTrashed()`
>   method.

Normally, Laravel deletes all relationship data via `$board->projects()->delete()`, but i didn't understand your problem. When you run `$board->projects()->delete()` command what happened?. Normally, when use it, it should be delete all `projects` from projects table.

> **Note;** For the next your delete works, you may want use
>   [DB::transaction](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database#database-transactions) for sure deleting on relationship data.

EDIT;

When a board is deleting do you want delete relationship projects data, you can use following method.

```
DB::transaction(function () use ($board) {
    $board->projects()->delete();
    $board->delete();
});
```

The above codes, if projects was deleted correctly, deletes given board. If a problem occurs on the delete, it doesn't delete anything thanks to `DB::transaction`.

Comment: It only deleted the relationship, but the data still exists. If I have 4 projects that belong to a Board, how to I get rid of them all at once without knowing their ID's?